# Scala Mock Syntax (class _).expects meaning?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, scalamock

New to Scala, have searched far and wide for clarification on some ScalaMock syntax. As per [this guide](https://scalamock.org/user-guide/mocking_style/), I keep seeing the following general testing pattern:

`(myClass.myMethod _).expects()`

What exactly is happening here? What function does the class/method/space/underscore serve? How does the compiler treat this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appended `_` forces the conversion of a method into a function.

To understand why this is necessary, let's try to re-build a tiny piece of Scalamock, namely the `expects` method. The `expects` method seems to be invoked on methods of mocked objects. But methods / functions do not have an `expects` method to begin with. Therefore, we have to use the "pimp my library"-pattern to attach the method `expects` to functions. We could do something like this:

```
implicit class ExpectsOp[A, B](f: A => B) {
  def expects(a: A): Unit = println("it compiles, ship it...")
}
```

Now let's define a class `Bar` with method `baz`:

```
class Bar {
  def baz(i: Int): Int = i * i
}
```

and also an instance of `Bar`:

```
val bar = new Bar
```

Let's see what happens if you try to invoke `expects` on `bar.baz`:

```
(bar.baz).expects(42)
```

> error: missing argument list for method baz in class Bar
>   Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. You can make this conversion explicit by writing `baz _` or `baz(_)` instead of `baz`.

So, it doesn't work without explicit conversion into a function, and we have to enforce this conversion by appending an `_`:

```
(bar.baz _).expects(42) // prints: "it compiles, ship it..."
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This exactly answers my question.